# Is it practically safe to cast container of T* to container of const T*?

Tags: pointers, containers, reinterpret-cast

For instance,

```
std::vector<SomeNonCopyableType*> values = getVector();
auto &cvalues = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<const SomeNonCopyableType*>&>(values);

// use cvalues...
```

This is not allowed in standard of course.
However, constness of pointed type won't make any difference in implementation detail unless they're specialized. In this case, may I consider this conversion is safe practically?

If it is a bad idea, is there graceful way to make a container of pointer to const from container of pointer to non-const without making copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically speaking yes, but it's not what you should be doing. Instead of aliasing the container, use its `const_iterator` type to work with the range of elements contained in the container. (You can use the experimental `std::experimental::ranges::Range` struct to help with this if you like.)

Comment: When you dereference std::vector<T*>::const_iterator type, you will get T *const(const pointer) not const T*(pointer to const).